# C# webBrowser object

Tags: c#, browser

I'm using the webBrowser object to surf to a page that has an Iframe.
I'm trying to get the Specific objects in this iframe by using the GetElementByID function.
I do something like this: webBrowser1.document.GetelementByID("iframeName").document.GetElementByID("ElementName)

It doesn't work. I get Null.

Any ideas?

TY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Document` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.document.aspx) gets the `HtmlDocument` object that owns the element, not the document in the `<iframe>`.

Instead, you should use the [`HtmlWindow.Frames` collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlwindow.frames.aspx), like this:

```
myWebBrowser.Document.Window.Frames["IFrameName"].Document.GetElementByID("ElementName")
```

Comment: HEYYYYYY!!!! Perfect!!!!
I was looking for this solution for a long time.
Thank you very much.